# Why is there no R `formula` parameter in Scikit-learn models?

Tags: scikit-learn, r

I was comparing both R and Python implementations of various models,
such as [Generalized Boosted Regression](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gbm/versions/2.1.8/topics/gbm) and [Generalized Linear Models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#generalized-linear-regression), and I was wondering why in R it is usual to see the `formula` parameter and in Scikit-lean it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The question is why was scikit designed this way. Only a few people can factually answer that question. I have my opinion, but that is all that it is.

However formulas can be used with scikit or statsmodels or other packages.  [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) gives the ability. This can be used with scikit as the output of Patsy functions a lot like numpy arrays.  An example is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/patsy-build-powerful-features-with-arbitrary-python-code-bb4bb98db67a).

The choice to use formulas or work with matrices would be up to the individual.